# MySQL; GROUP BY but only if column is not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY B,D,F;
```

If there are some rows where `B` is empty and `D` is empty AND `F` is empty, it'll grouped to a single row where all the three columns are empty.

But instead I want: in case all three columns (B, D, F) of a row are empty don't group this row show it.

Means: If I have the following:

[image]

result should be:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Add sample data and expected result to make it clear

Comment: `select *` with `group by` is an abomination.  Provide sample data and desired results to explain what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Just added sample data.

Comment: So you want to group rows that are the same, and keep empty ones? Also preserve the order?

Comment: @davidbaumann Yes, you're right. But it's not important to preserve the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are selecting * with group by !! not sure if this is going to work with you.

Anyway, to achieve what you want try this

```
SELECT B,D,F
FROM your_table
WHERE NOT (B='' AND D='' AND F='')
GROUP BY B,D,F

UNION ALL

SELECT B,D,F
FROM your_table
WHERE B='' AND D='' AND F=''
```

Comment: What is `Min()` and `Sum()`?

Comment: @David you dont need them, I modified my query

Comment: It seems OP wants `UNION ALL`, for retrieving all rows with all empty columns.

Comment: @OtoShavadze What's the difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM my_table GROUP BY B,D,F,IF((B="" AND D="" AND F=""),id,0);
```

assuming that id is a unique key.

if any of the columns you want to group by aren't empty, zero is retuned instead of id, but if all three ARE empty, then id is returned, and thus ones with all three others empty are no longer grouped.

And yes, this works with select *.

Comment: Please explain how/why you answer works. Good answers receive more upvoted. Explanations make answers easier to read (and thus become more upvoted) and they are easier to understand. Answers that give future users insights on how to solve their own coding issues tend to receive more upvotes over time, as more people learn something new, and more people fix related issues of their own. Consider editing your answer to provide your insight to future visitors.

Comment: The IF provides a fourth key to group by, which is unique. but replaces it with zero if b d or f aren't empty. So if there is anything in B D or F, then it's turned to zero, so they will group properly. But if all three are empty, then the fourth grouped key will change, and separate them.

Comment: Great! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71044530/edit) to add this to the body of your answer :-)